# How to avoid user to click outside popup Dialog window using Qt and Python?

Tags: qt, user-interface, python-3.x, dialog, qt-creator

I created a Dialog window using Qt Creator and Python.
I would like that Window stays on the top of my Gui AND avoid users to click outside that Dialog Until this dialog was closed.

Comment: The term you are looking for is "modal dialog."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `setModal()` like so;

```
dialog.setModal(1);
```

Or;

```
dialog.setModal(true);
```